# Angularjs ng-repeat index not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use ng-repeat more or less as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="One_Entry in Entries_List track by One_Entry.Entry_ID"
     onClick="DoSomething(One_Entry.Entry_ID)">

      <!--- 
      present various fields within "One_Entry"
      -->

</div>
```

`Entries_List` is a JSON array of objects, being `Entry_ID` one of the elements within the object.

`DoSomething` is a function within the related controller that is supposed to perform a specific activity on the structure whose ID is the passed Entry_ID.

I tried using `$index` as well as `$parent.$index` but I'm getting an error stating that these variable do not exist.

Could anyone tell me how I can achieve the above functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object One_Entry is scoped. Therefore onclick won't work. Use ng-click instead which is the Angular version for onclick:

```
<div ng-repeat="One_Entry in Entries_List track by One_Entry.Entry_ID"
     ng-click="DoSomething(One_Entry.Entry_ID)">

  <!--- 
  present various fields within "One_Entry"
  -->

</div>
```

Comment: I wrote the following: `ng-click="alert('ggg')"` and nothing happened (no alert, no error message. Nothing.

Comment: Alert is not a function unless you create it in the controller by $scope.alert = function(txt) {alert(txt);}. Then you can call it by ng-click="alert('ggg')".

Comment: Btw, is the function DoSomething created in the controller and added to the $scope? Like $scope.DoSomething = function () { //Do something }

Comment: GOOD CATCH!!!!! The `@scope.` was missing in the function declaration within the controller. Now it works perfectly. Thanks @NiklasMH!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not `OnClick` it's `ng-click`

Change

**From :**

```
<div ng-repeat="One_Entry in Entries_List track by One_Entry.Entry_ID"
 onClick="DoSomething(One_Entry.Entry_ID)">
```

**To:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="One_Entry in Entries_List track by One_Entry.Entry_ID"
     ng-click="DoSomething(One_Entry.Entry_ID)">
```

Comment: Well, the problem does not seam to be there because the function is fired (i.e. if I deploy within the function a simple alert, I get the message). On the other hand, if I use ng-click, the function is not fired at all.

Comment: can you creatae a plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan for your response. Please see my last comment to the previous solution. My error was that the function to be invoked was missing the `$scope.` prefix within the controller.